# Selenium - Xpath pathing to table Syntax Problem

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, path

I want to extract the ¨BMW Serie 2 Active Tourer¨ table, first column, which appears by clicking ¨MOSTRAR VERSIONES (14)¨ in https://motorgiga.com/bmw/2-series.

The Xpath '//div[@data-nql="ve:car:bmw:serie-2-active-tourer"]' works.

The Xpath '//div[@data-nql="ve:car:bmw:serie-2-active-tourer"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a'
doesn't work.

Can you please help me to write correctly the Xpath syntax to get here?

The script tries to get the table through the tag "serie-2-active-tourer", since i want to relate each table to its model.

Pd: my screen capture is at the end, showing the html.

Thank you,

Jose Luis

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless') # ESTO ES OROOOO
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu') # ESTO ES OROOOO :)



driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=r"chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
url = 'https://motorgiga.com/bmw/2-series/precios'
driver.get(url)

# 1. This works

xpath = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-nql="ve:car:bmw:serie-2-active-tourer"]')
result = [xpath[i].get_attribute('class') for i in range(0, len(list(xpath)))]
print(result)

# 2. Now we enter into the table division. This doesn't work

xpath = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
'//div[@data-nql="ve:car:bmw:serie-2-active-tourer"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a')
```

My html screen capture: [www.i.stack.imgur.com/Z0V0U.png](https://www.i.stack.imgur.com/Z0V0U.png)

Comment: find_elements on a single element?

Comment: @arundeep chohan I would prefer find_elements because I want to get the whole column, but if you can get one element, it should be easy to change for the whole column.

But I need to differentiate each table, there is more than one